# put words to specific position in line

Tags: linux, file, shell, awk

I have a file and it contains data as:

```
905222105114 BAHADIR ADANA 2122121

905222105114 ISTANBUL ANKARA 213123

0012312554645 ANTALYA BAHADIR 2312312
```

I want to put these datas in another file.

N.1 value must start in 0 position of line.

N.2 value must start in 20 position of line.

N.3 value must start in 40 position of line.

N.4 value must start in 60 position of line.

By this way, I'll get a file that each value starts at current position of line.

Comment: can you show the output for the given input?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{printf "%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4}' file.dat
```

should do the trick...